# read double quotes and single quotes from Sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsstring, uitextview

In my application I am trying to read some data from sqlite database into UITextView.

This text has double quotes as well as single quotes, for ex:

> she said : "Katie's purse has been
>   lost"

when I do this, I get strange characters in place of double and single quotes. Please help me with a solution to scrub these characters off.

Thanks.

Comment: As always, it would help everyone out if you could post your code. (I would wager it's some kind of string encoding issue, especially if you're using the SQLite C APIs.)

Answer (score 2):

If you get one strange character (or set of characters) replacing `"` and another replacing `'`, you can just scan the string and replace.  If you aren't, then:

1. That's very strange, and
2. You should post your code.